# error java.lang.illegalstateexception begin object but was begin array at line 1 column 6 path $ error in android studio kotlin

Tags: android

This is my kotlin code and this kind of error generating.

> java.lang.illegalstateexception begin object but was begin array at line 1 column 6 path $

```
binding.animalsoundimg.setOnClickListener {
    var call2 = apiinterface.getanimalsound()
    call2.enqueue(object : Callback<animalsound> {
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<animalsound>, response: Response<animalsound>
        ) {
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                val soundUrl = response.body()?.soundurl

                if (soundUrl != null) {
                    PlayAnimalSound(soundUrl)
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<animalsound>, t: Throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Error" + t.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

    })
}


private fun PlayAnimalSound(soundurl: String) {
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(soundurl)
    mediaPlayer.prepare()
    mediaPlayer.start()
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    mediaPlayer.release()
}
```

I have try everything for this code but not solved please resolve this

Comment: Can you please share the response that you are getting from api and the model that you have created

Comment: this is my apiclint https://rutvikbabariya1013.000webhostapp.com/Project_Api/ and this is my apiinterface // For Animal Sound
    @GET("animal_voice_view.php")
    fun getanimalsound():Call<animalsound> and this is model class package com.example.myanimal.AppModel



class animalsound
{
    var id=0
    var soundurl=""
}

Comment: can you give me full code because i am new in android studio i have just make this my first app

Answer (score 0):

From your reference you are using [animal_voice_view.php](https://rutvikbabariya1013.000webhostapp.com/Project_Api/animal_voice_view.php) API and response is in Array format and the Data Class you have passed in `Response<animalsound>` it contains only Object from Array.

You should update your data class `animalsound` with this

```
class animalsound : ArrayList<AnimalSoundItem>()

data class AnimalSoundItem(
    val id: String,
    val soundUrl: String
)
```

Access Object within array like this

```
val animalSound = animalSoundList[position]
animalSound.id
animalSound.soundurl
```